# Validating the xml:id Attribute in an XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm fairly new to XML, and to coding in general.

I'm trying to validate an XML markup with a schema that I've put together. One of my elements utilizes the xml:id attribute. It looks like this: `<item xml:id="MAT_10_23">`. In my schema, I've followed the recommended structure with `<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>` in the element declaration. Here it is in full:

```
<xs:element name="item">
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="label">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I try to validate this my markup, however, I'm told that "Attribute xml:id is not allowed to appear in the element ". I've tried declaring the attribute separately in my schema separately. This is what it looks like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
```

But this does not change anything. What do I need to change in my schema to successfully validate my XML markup?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared an attribute with local name id in no namespace, when you want the attribute to be in the XML namespace. You need to:

(a) replace the attribute declaration by

```
<xs:attribute ref="xml:id"/>
```

(b) add an xs:import for the schema for the XML namespace (which contains a declaration of this attribute):

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
```

You may also need to add a `schemaLocation` attribute to provide a location for a copy of this schema document - some schema processors will recognize the namespace and know where to find its definition, but I don't think that this is true of all processors.

Comment: Okay, when I enter <xs:attribute ref="xml:id"/> into my schema, it tells me that "Attribute 'ref' cannot appear in element 'attribute'". Will the schemaLocation address this?

Comment: You need to make the replacement in your first attempt, where the attribute is locally declared, not in the second attempt where you try to declare it globally.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!